# Mensaje personalizado al producirse el "Error 1004" cuando falla una macro

Tags: excel, vba

soy nuevo por acá en el foro... mi inquietud es la siguiente, tengo una macro en un formulario que funciona mediante un botón de buscar. Los campos "cargo" y "nombre" se encargan de buscar en la hoja3 la similitud que haya con lo que se escriba en el campo "masCedula". Cuando se produce el "Error 1004" es porque la cédula que se busca no existe en la hoja3 ¿Cómo hago para que en vez de que me aparezca este mensaje de error 1004 que me interrumpe mi aplicación, me aparezca un mensaje personalizado?

```
Dim fila As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim cargo, nombre As String

fila = Hoja3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
cargo = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Val(masCedula), Hoja3.Range("A2:H" & fila), 2, 0) 'busca el cargo de cedula
nombre = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Val(masCedula), Hoja3.Range("A2:H" & fila), 3, 0) 'busca el nombre de la cedula

If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "Esta cédula no existe", vbExclamation, "DATAPAD 3.3 - Error"
    masCedula = ""
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los errores se manejan con "On Error Goto". Escribe tu código así:

```
Dim fila As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim cargo, nombre As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

fila = Hoja3.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
cargo = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Val(masCedula), Hoja3.Range("A2:H" & fila), 2, 0) 'busca el cargo de cedula
nombre = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Val(masCedula), Hoja3.Range("A2:H" & fila), 3, 0) 'busca el nombre de la cedula


ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "Esta cédula no existe", vbExclamation, "DATAPAD 3.3 - Error"
    masCedula = ""
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Con "On Error Goto" le estás "diciendo" que si encuentra algún error en la ejecución vaya a una zona específica del código donde se manejan los errores. Y desde esa "zona" podrás manejar cualquier tipo de error.

Comment: dogwall funciona bien... muchas gracias

Comment: Solo con el afán de aportar algo a vuestra problemática: si bien es correcto siempre tener una rutina para el control de errores, están asumiendo que si hay un error será siempre porque no se encontró el registro y por lo que entiendo Error 1004 es error en ejecución se podría dar otro caso que diese ese error; no sería mejor realizar un conteo del total de los registros para saber si llego al final y si llego al final y no hallo el registro entonces ahí si enviar el mensaje "Cedula no Existe".

Comment: Llevas razón. La solución no es la mejor, pues el error 1004 puede generarse de muchas formas.